# Change cell color and assign value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel schedule system where in BB13:BB40 column has plan and action cells.

What I am trying to do:
If BC13:DT40 is selected with mouse or clicked with mouse (e.g. BC:13DT) it should check the BB row (BB13).
If it has 'action' the selected area should change color to red if it has plan it should change to blue.
If the cell already has color then it should get cleared.

```vb
Sub ChangeCellColor()
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Set the target range
    Set targetRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BC13:DT40")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the target range
    For Each cell In targetRange
        ' Check the value of the corresponding BB cell
        If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Action" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Change to red
        ElseIf cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Plan" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Change to blue
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using Conditional Formatting for this?

Comment: Just insert your code to a worksheet module (same worksheet you want to monitor) under `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

Comment: @CLR because in future(stage 2) I want to be able to assign each colored cell value(of 15min) in this way I want to calculate the total planned time for each task and actual time. I am not sure if its possible through condtional formatting

Comment: @ShaiRado I did but it doesnt work there's no error either. I also changed the name of sheet accordingly but it won't work

Comment: Do you want BC13 > DT13 to all at once change colour based on the value in BB13? Or do you want BC13 to be based on BB13, BD13 to be based on BC13, BE13 on BD13 etc..?

Comment: To make it easier, say ... a user select a block of cells, B2:C5. All cells within B2:C5 has no value. Your code do a loop to each cell within that user selection cells (B2:C5). The first iteration is B2, B2 offset(0,-1) value is "Action" ... so you want cell B2 has red color. The second iteration is C2. C2 offset(0,-1) is B2 which has no value but red color, so what you want to happen to C2 ? The third iteration is B3 which already have a blue color. B3 offset(0,-1) is A3 with "Action" value. What color you want for B3? clear the blue to none, or change blue to red? And what happen to C3 ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("BC13:DT40")) Is Nothing Then
    
        If Me.Cells(Target.Row, "BB").Value = "Action" Then
            Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf Me.Cells(Target.Row, "BB").Value = "Plan" Then
            Target.Interior.Color = vbBlue
        Else
            'clear interior color if value other than action or plan
            Target.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```